# How to reset a form with required fields in Angular 1.X and Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

It looks like Angular is not clearing the *required* error message when I call, $setPristine, $setUntouched and $setValidity. However other error messages can clear by simply setting null.

```
reset() {
    this.form.amount = null;
    this.paymentForm.$setPristine();
    this.paymentForm.$setUntouched();
    this.paymentForm.$setValidity();
  }
```

Please refer to the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/boINmB?p=preview

Comment: that looks like a question for the angular-material project.

Comment: @DanielA.White probably you are correct. looks material change the default way of angular messages work and probably this particular use case is a bug.

Comment: @DanielA.White here you go! It's a bug in Angular Material and like most of other issues project owners marked this issue as "deprecated" and thread is now locked. https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1903

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am publishing the answer (possible workaround) to this Angular Material defect. Just add the following style to your project and should fix the problem.

```
<style>
  .ng-untouched ~ .md-input-messages-animation {
     height: 0;
     opacity: 0;
     transition: height 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing `this.form.amount` in your reset function

```
reset() {
  this.form.amount = null;
  this.paymentForm.$setPristine();
  this.paymentForm.$setUntouched();
  this.paymentForm.$setValidity();
}
```

... and `$ctrl.paymentForm.amount.$error` in your HTML.

```
<div ng-messages="$ctrl.paymentForm.amount.$error" role="alert">
  <div ng-message="required">Field is required</div>
  <div ng-message="dollar">Invalid dollar</div>
  <div ng-message="max">You don't have enough money</div>
  <div ng-message="dailyLimit">Daily payment limit reached</div>
</div>
```

Change `this.form` to `this.paymentForm` and it works:

```
reset() {
  this.paymentForm.amount = null;
  this.paymentForm.$setPristine();
  this.paymentForm.$setUntouched();
  this.paymentForm.$setValidity();
}
```

Comment: Your change will directly modify the value in FormController and this only going to work once and then entire validation starts malfunctioning for the amount field. Steps to re-produce, 1) Focus on the field 2) Focus out from the field and you can see the required error 3) press clear button so required error hides ( so far so good ) 4)  Focus on field again and focus out . 5) Required error message not getting displayed ( not good )

Answer (score 0):

Change `this.form.amount = null` to `this.form.amount = undefined` or `delete this.form.amount`

```
 reset() {
    delete this.form.amount;
    this.paymentForm.$setPristine();
    this.paymentForm.$setUntouched();
    this.paymentForm.$setValidity();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `this.paymentForm.$setPristine(true)`

Comment: Still angular not hiding the required error message. Please feel free to play with the plunker